# IN R counting hierarchical data

Tags: r, count, hierarchical-data

I have a list of counties in each state that received nonattainment status in years 1995-2005.

I want to know how many counties in each state each year that received this status.

If my data is formatted like this,

```
State1 Country1 YR1 Yr2 Yr3 Yr4...
State1 Country2 YR1 Yr2 Yr3 Yr4
State2 County1  Yr1 Yr2.....
```

Each year variable could have a 1 or a zero, since a county may gain or lose this status in a time period.

I need to count each year how many counties in each state have nonattainment status (YRx=1), but can't think of how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

I used the following example:

```
data <- read.table(textConnection("
state county Yr1 Yr2 Yr3 Yr4
state1 county1 1 0 0 1
state1 county2 0 0 0 0
state1 county3 0 1 0 0
state1 county4 0 0 0 0
state1 county5 0 1 0 1
state2 county6 0 0 0 0
state2 county7 0 0 1 0
state2 county8 1 0 0 1
state2 county9 0 0 0 0
state2 county10 0 1 0 0
state3 county11 1 1 1 1
state3 county12 0 0 0 0
state3 county13 0 1 1 0
state3 county14 0 0 0 1
state4 county15 0 0 0 0
state4 county16 1 0 1 0
state4 county17 0 0 0 0
state4 county18 1 1 1 1
"), header = T)

library(reshape)
data2 <- melt(data, id = c("state", "county"))
cast(data2, state ~ variable, fun = sum)
```

Result:

```
   state Yr1 Yr2 Yr3 Yr4
1 state1   1   2   0   2
2 state2   1   1   1   1
3 state3   1   2   2   2
4 state4   2   1   2   1
```

Comment: wow, thanks a lot.  i have been struggling on this all afternoon.  i'll try it out.

Answer (score 0):

Is this data organized as a dataframe? If so, how are the rows defined? If your data were organized this way:

```
State   County  Year    Attainment  
State1   County1  1       1  
State1   County1  2       0
State1   County1  3       1
State1   County1  4       1
State1   County2  1       1
State1   County2  2       1
...
```

Then it would be possible to get the kind of summary data you're looking for with 1 line of code. Hopefully your notation means that your data is organized like this:

```
State   County  Yr1 Yr2 Yr3 Yr4
State1   County1 1  0   1   1
State1   County2 1  1   1   1
```

Use `melt()` from the `reshape` package to get from this format to the one laid out above.

```
new.df <- melt(df, id = 1:2)
```

It'll call the Year variable `variable` and the Attainment variable `value`. Now, with clever use of the `cast` function, also from the `reshape` package, you can get the summary you want.

```
counties <- cast(new.df, State ~ value, fun = length)
head(counties)
```

However, if your data is organized so that every state, county and year is a column, and it's only 1 row long, I think your best next step would be to reformat the data outside of R so that it looks at least like my second example.

Comment: it is organized the second way. i thought i formatted my question correctly, but when i posted it, it merged into one line.

Comment: JoFrhwld- I did that, but it game me the summaries for all years, not total for each year.  I'm still working on this problem, if you have any suggestions I would appreciate it.  Your help has gotten me further at least!!